# Relations in a certain Lie algebra

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras

Let ${\mathfrak g}$ be the (real) Lie algebra generated by infinitely many generators $D_i, E_i$ with $i=1,2,3,\dots$ subject to the following relations for any natural numbers $i,j$:
\begin{gather*}
[D_i, D_j] = [E_i, E_j] = 0 \\
[D_i, E_j] = [D_j, E_i].
\end{gather*}
Let ${\mathfrak h}$ be the Lie subalgebra of ${\mathfrak g}$ generated just by the $[D_i,E_j]$, $E_i$ for natural numbers $i, j$.  Obviously, this subalgebra obeys the relations
$$ [D_i,E_j]=[D_j,E_i]; \quad [E_i, E_j] = 0 \tag{*}\label{464808_star}$$
and from the Jacobi identity one also has
$$ [E_i, [D_j, E_k]] = [E_k, [D_j, E_i]]. \tag{**}\label{464808_starstar}$$

**Question**: are these a generating set of relations for ${\mathfrak h}$?  That is to say, are there any other relations between $[D_i,E_j]$ and $E_i$ that are not a consequence of \eqref{464808_star} and \eqref{464808_starstar} (and the axioms of a Lie algebra)?

In trying to settle this question, I discovered a large number of combinations of the $D_i, E_i$ that were symmetric in the indices.  From the above relations \eqref{464808_star}, \eqref{464808_starstar}, for instance, $[D_i, E_j]$ and $[E_i, [D_j, E_k]]$ are both symmetric in their respective indices, but so are
\begin{gather*}
[D_i, [D_j, E_k]] \\
[D_i, [D_j, [D_k, E_l]]] \\
[D_i, [E_j, [D_k, E_l]] - \frac{1}{2} [[D_i,E_j], [D_k, E_l]] - \frac{1}{2} [[D_i,E_k], [D_j,E_l]] - \frac{1}{2} [[D_i,E_l], [D_j,E_k]]
\end{gather*}
and so forth.  Thus far I have found that every Lie bracket word in the $D_i, E_j$, such as $[D_i, [E_j, [D_k, E_l]]$, seems to extend to an expression symmetric in the indices after adding lower order (or more precisely, lower depth) terms, but I cannot prove this conclusively (and I suspect it is somehow related to the above question); as the words get longer it seems that an increasing number of algebraic miracles are required to obtain the full symmetry in the indices.

Having a faithful representation of these Lie algebras would of course also be very helpful, but I was not able to come up with a tractable candidate for such a representation.

Comment: Write $F_{ij}=[D_i,E_j]$. You thus define the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{l}$ with generators $F_{ij}$, $E_i$, relators $F_{ij}=F_{ji}$, $[E_i,E_j]=0$, $[E_i,F_{jk}]=[E_k,F_{ij}]$, and ask whether its natural homomorphism to $\mathfrak{g}$ is injective. From this presentation it appears that the $F_{ij}$, $i\le j$, form a free family (i.e. freely generate a Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{l}$). This is obvious by killing the $E_i$ in the given presentation of $\mathfrak{l}$. Do the images $[D_i,E_j]$ ($i\le j$) freely generate a subalgebra in $\mathfrak{g}$?

Comment: @YCor: Consider  $[[D_i, E_j], E_i]$. Expand using the Jacobi identity:

$[[D_i, E_j], E_i] = -[E_j, [E_i, D_i]] - [E_i, [D_i, E_j]] = 0$


 terms vanish due to antisymmetry $([E_i, E_i] = [D_i, E_i] = 0)$.

Comment: @YCor: Now, consider $[[D_i, E_j], E_k]$ (where k ≠ i). Then
 
$[[D_i, E_j], E_k] = -[E_j, [D_i, E_k]]$ $[[D_i, E_j], E_i] = 0$ for any i, j
$[[D_i, E_j], E_k] = -[E_j, [D_i, E_k]]$ for i ≠ k

Comment: Therefore, the $[D_i, E_j]$( i ≤ j) do not freely generate a subalgebra in g.

Comment: The key relation seems to induce  a cascading reduction. We can repeatedly pull out E elements to the front of nested commutators.

Comment: @Damien You have just reproved ($**$) of Terry's post.

Comment: But isn’t $[[D_i, E_j], E_i] + [[D_i, E_j], E_k] = 0 $$ an example  of relations between [Di,Ej] and Ei that are not a consequence of (*) and (**)?

Comment: A (maybe) faithful representation?:

D_i -> (1/i) * x^i * d/dx
E_i -> d/dx + c * x (where c is a constant)

Commutator Relations:  Our representation faithfully satisfies:

[D_i, D_j] = 0
[E_i, E_j] = 0
[D_i, E_j] = c * δ_ij * F (where F acts as 'multiplication by x')

Key Extensions

Pseudo-Derivative D^-1:

Proposed Behavior: D^-1 * (d/dx) = 1 (Identity)
Modified Product Rule: D^-1 (x * f(x)) = f(x) + x * D^-1 (f(x))

Comment: @Damien First, these are not relations between the $F_{ij}$. Second, these are precisely the relations ($**$).

Comment: @Damien D_i -> (1/i) * x^i * d/dx do not commute with each other.